# Split output of LSTM to do computation on each vector in keras/tensorflow

Tags: vector, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensor

I'm trying to implement a custom layer in keras. At the end it should implement an Attention Layer. So what i want to do is take the output of an LSTM and make a computation on every vector of the output.

I've got an LSTM with return-sequence=True. So I get an output with a shape like `(batch_size, num_vectors, dim_vector)`.

How can I access a single vector in the call-function of the custom-layer? Or better, how can i split the input tensor to get a list of tensors with shape `(dim_vector)`. 
So it should be `batch_size * num_vectors` vectors/tensors in this list.

What i want to do looks kind of like this:

```
for i in range(num_vectors):
    x_i = list_of_vectors/tensors[i]

    W = self.W.eval().transponse()
    W1 = self.W1.eval()
    b = self.b.eval()
    b1 = self.b1.eval()

    activated = self.kernel_activation(W1.dot(x_i) + b1)
    score = W.dot(activated) + b
    scores.append(score)
```

What looks kind a promising but is poorly documented is `K.gather()`. Maybe someone could explain how it is working or has a better idea how to deal with my problem.

I also tried `tf.unstack()` to get a list. But this doesn't work because the dimensions of my input-tensor are unknown except of dim_vector.

I'm working with keras on tensorflow-backend.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try `tf.reshape`

Comment: I did that and its working now. But I have to specify the batch_size in the Layer-init. Is there a better way to do what i want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what the situation is now. Maybe you should make a new question with the updated code?